# Fix for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory's XXE flaw (CWE ID 611) flagged by Veracode scans in Android

Tags: android, xml, docx, veracode

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory is used in our Android app to parse and read xml as well as to modify and write to the xml file. Veracode flags the usage of javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory with CWE ID 611 "Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference". The suggested remediation is "Configure the XML parser to disable external entity resolution." And the OWASP documentation mentions several features that can be set using the setFeature method on the factory. However the issue is that this fix throws a "javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl". The reason is that the Android implementation returns "org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl" when the newInstance() method of the factory is called and this builder class implementation does not support setFeature for the OWASP recommended features.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(xmlFile);
```

The above code gets flagged. The code's functionality is parsing the underlying xml files that make up a .docx document. We can convert the read xml part of this code to use the Android recommended XmlPullParser but XmlPullParser cannot be used to modify these xml files as our current code uses DocumentBuilderFactory to both read these XMLs that make up the .docx file and modify the XMLs when exporting the docx files.

Have spent a couple of days searching for possible solutions and was not able to find any solutions that work. Any help/recommendations on how can we solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!